# Django reverse db lookup for multiple objects

Tags: mysql, django, performance, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a model called *TicketSection* and *TicketSubmission* the models look like this: (simplified)

```py
class TicketSection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="35")
    weight = models.IntegerField()

class TicketSubmission(models.Model):
    ticket_section = models.ForeignKey('myapp.TicketSection')
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    submiter = models.ForeignKey('myapp.User')
    submiting_account = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Account')
```

Now I want to filter TicketSections with it's TicketSubmissions. So I do:

```py
ticket_sections = TicketSection.objects.filter(weight__gte=50).annotate(some_additional_logic)

# Generated SQL Query: SELECT * FROM myapp_ticketsection
               WHERE weight >= 50
```

I know you can select reverse objects by

```py
ticket_sections[0].ticketsubmission_set.filter(again_some_logic).annotate(logic)


# Generated SQL Query: SELECT * FROM myapp_ticketsubmission
              WHERE ticket_section = [id of ticket section]
```

But how do I do it for all ticket sections and how do I use it in template? Should I do:

```py
for ticket_sec in ticket_sections: 
    ticket_sec.submissions = ticket_sec.ticketsubmission_set.filter(again_some_logic).annotate(logic)
```

and then in template

```
{% for ticket_sec in ticket_section %}
    {% for submission in ticket_sec.submissions %}
        {{ submission.cost }}
```

^ But that doesn't seem like the right way for me. So how should I reverse lookup for multiple objects to minimalize database hits?

I'm using **Django 2.2.5** with **MySQL** database.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames Added generated SQL Queries, however I'm unsure how it helps. Because I would like to reach the goal with Django's ORM. I can write .Raw() query but then I lose relationship lookups and some other stuff.

Comment: Those two `SELECTs` can probably be done as one, using a `JOIN ... ON the ticket id`.